# NLog Database Parameter + .NET Core: all-event-properties in JSON?

Tags: json, asp.net-core, nlog, structured-logging

I am using the Database target and trying to figure out a way to send `all-event-properties` as a parameter in JSON format; I see that parameter includes a property for "format," but when I do `format="json"` it doesn't produce the desired effect.

Here's what I have in my nlog.config file:

```
<target name="database">
    <parameter name="@properties" layout="${all-event-properties}" format="json" />
</target>
```

Unfortunately my properties are still getting logged in the format

```
property1=property1, property2=property2, property3=property3
```

What I'm expecting to see is

```
{
    "property1": "property1",
    "property2": "property2",
    "property3": "property3"
}
```

Please advise.  Thank you!

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4116

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<target name="database" type="database">
    <parameter name="@properties">
        <layout type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="1" escapeForwardSlash="false" />
    </parameter>
</target>
```

See also: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/JsonLayout